# Gulp, concat and uglify files and concat with vendor

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

I want to concat and uglify my JS files with gulp. After that I want to conact the result with a vendor folder which includes jquery, bootstrap, ...

How can I concat the files from the vendor folder after uglify my js code?

Here is my current gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src([
          './src/resources/assets/js/**/*.js',
          '!./src/resources/assets/js/vendor/**/*.js'
      ])
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts'], function() {
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly, you want to concat your js.files with the libraries, but keep a concat version of your own js ?

I would do that, you get to keep both files :

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('myJs', function() {
  gulp.src([
          './src/resources/assets/js/**/*.js',
          '!./src/resources/assets/js/vendor/**/*.js'
      ])
    .pipe(concat('myJs.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'));
});

gulp.task('allJs', function() {
    gulp.src([
          './src/resources/assets/js/vendor/**/*.js',
          './public/js/myJs.js'
      ])
    .pipe(concat('allJs.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'));
})


gulp.task('default', function() {
  runSequence('myJs',
              'allJs',
              );
});
```

or that, you only keep one file :

```
var merge = require('merge2');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    // Get your js
    var myJs = gulp.src([
        src + 'my/*.js',
        src + '!not/my/*.js'])

    // Get vendor js
    var vendorJs = gulp.src(src + 'not/my/*.js')

    return merge(myJs, vendorJs)
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```